# Как составить sql-запрос, с использованием данных из другой таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Есть mysql-таблицы следующего вида:

1-ая таблица(Разделы):
`id`

2-ая таблица(Подразделы):
`section_id` -> содержит id строки из первой таблицы

3-я таблица(Топики):
`subsection_id` -> содержит id строки из второй таблицы

Топики относятся к подразделам, подразделы относятся к разделам. Нужно составить sql-запрос, который по id раздела ищет связанные с ним подразделы, а далее ищет топики связанные с этими подразделами.
СУБД - mysql.

Comment: Нужно - составляйте. PS. Обычный JOIN.

Comment: В том-то и проблема, что времени нет, а запрос нужно написать сейчас.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал сам с помощью запроса, может кому пригодится на начальных стадиях:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM topics, subsections 
WHERE topics.subsection_id = subsections.id 
  AND subsections.section_id = :section_id
```

Думал join будет изучаться очень долго, на самом же деле за 10 минут нашел статью и понял как они пишутся)

Comment: Как раз JOIN Вы и не используете...

Comment: Зануда... 
SELECT t1.* FROM topics AS t1 LEFT JOIN subsections AS t2 ON t1.subsection_id = t2.id WHERE t2.section_id = :section_id
Вот так стоит в итоге)

Comment: Почти. Только INNER JOIN. Всё равно условие по правой таблице во WHERE делает связывание внутренним - так зачем заставлять сервер делать ненужную работу, результат которой будет гарантированно проигнорирован?

Comment: Можно по-подробнее что именно будет за ненужная работа? Сервер сначала при LEFT JOIN вытащит все строки, в том числе частично подходящие, а потом отсеит через условие WHERE, тем самым будет эта ненужная работа?

Comment: Сравним INNER и LEFT JOIN. Как выполняется второй? Сперва берутся все записи из левой, которым есть соотв. записи в правой, формируются пары (как при INNER). Потом берутся из левой, не имеющие пары, и к ним вместо части от правой таблицы добавляются NULL. Дальше. Срабатывает WHERE по полю правой таблицы. Поскольку любое сравнение с NULL всегда трактуется как FALSE (кроме `<=>`), все добавленные записи с NULL-овой правой частью (т.е. все добавленные для преобразования INNER в LEFT) гарантированно отбрасываются. Вот это добавление с последующим гарантированным отбрасыванием и есть лишняя работа.

Comment: Благодарю за объяснение)